# How to delete Azure Website Webspace using MAML?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a WebSpace. From what I can tell, I have several empty WebSpaces in my subscription. I'd like to clean them up.

Using the Azure Management Library, I can list out the webspaces in my subscription. I can then list the websites to build a list of webspaces that contain 0 websites. I don't see a way to delete a webspace directly. I can delete a WebHostingPlan though.

The problem I'm having with the code below is when I try to get the WebHostingPlan for a given webspace, I don't get anything. Therefore, without the WebHostingPlan name, I can't delete it.

Does one not delete webspaces, but only WebHostingPlans?  Am I looking at this from the wrong point-of-view?

```
private async static Task DeleteEmptyWebspaces(SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials)
{
    using (var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(credentials))
    {
        var webspaces = await client.WebSpaces.ListAsync();

        IDictionary<string, string> spacesToDelete = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (WebSpacesListResponse.WebSpace space in webspaces)
        {
            var listWebSiteResponse = await client.WebSpaces.ListWebSitesAsync(space.Name, null);

            if (listWebSiteResponse.WebSites.Count == 0)
            {
                var hostingPlanListResponse = await client.WebHostingPlans.ListAsync(space.Name);
                if (hostingPlanListResponse.Any())
                {
                    // Assumption: Only one web hosting plan for a web space. Correct?
                    spacesToDelete.Add(space.Name, hostingPlanListResponse.WebHostingPlans[0].Name);
                }
            }
        }

         foreach (var space in spacesToDelete)
         {
            var deleteResponse = await client.WebHostingPlans.DeleteAsync(space.Key, space.Value);
            if (deleteResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete '{0}'.", space.Key);
            }
         }
    }
}
```